# Are Samsung Series 9 ultrabooks (purchased in the US) compatible with 240V/50Hz power input?

Tags: laptop, power, voltage, international

I'm traveling and I'm curious if I can use an adapter. I have a replacement power chord and it states that it can take in 100V-240V, 50-60Hz, but I want to make sure that the ultrabook itself accepts that kind of power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most computers use universal power supplys supporting both 60 and 50hz and 100 to 240v

on my european samsung i got [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834998831)  power supply with a eu plug instead of the us plug 
check the orginal power supply ratings and if they match your replacement then its ok :)

Comment: For the sake of clarity (I hope I'm just being pedantic), whether the power cord can take 100-240 volts is irrelevant - the key is the box transforming this "high voltage" down to the typical 15-20 volts a laptop uses.  If that box is rated at 100v-240v and 50-60 hertz, it will work anywhere as power is either nominally 100-120volts 60 hertz or 200-240 volts 50 hertz.